# pandas rolling mean skipping nans

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply a rolling function to a dataframe where if the current value is nan, it returns nan; else the rolling window W will **SKIP** nan values and apply to the **W non-nan** values. For example:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan,5]}, 
                       index=range(7))

    B
0   0.000000
1   1.000000
2   2.000000
3   nan
4   4.000000
5   nan
6   5.000000
```

For a rolling mean of window 3, the desired output is:

```
    B
0   nan
1   nan
2   1.000000
3   nan
4   2.333300
5   nan
6   3.666700
```

Notice 2.333 is mean of values (1,2,4) and 3.667 is mean of  values (2,4,5).

The rest of behavior, e.g. min_window, is the same as pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['B'].dropna().rolling(3).mean().reindex(df.index)
```